# create shortcut to the running tab on the android phone desktop

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to create a short cut to the `settings -> Apps -> Downloaded` and `settings -> Apps -> Running` tabs on the Android phone's desktop, so that I don't have to go through the menu all the time?

If that's not possible, is there any command I can issue from the `adb shell` that directly takes me to these tabs, and is there a way I can save it in a script file so that I can run it again with a single command?